# Updating min variable: min(a,b) vs. if statement

Tags: java, performance

What is better practice to keep track of the minimum in list:

```
int minVal = a[0];
for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
   minVal =  Math.min(minVal, a[i]);
}
```

or

```
int minVal = a[0];
for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
   if(a[i] < minVal)
       minVal =  a[i];
}
```

While the first code seems easier to read, the second one might be more efficient?

What is the text book way?

Comment: If we're talking about best practices;  [don't use multiline braceless ifs](http://cafe.elharo.com/blogroll/braceless-if-considered-harmful/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the implementation of `Math.min`:

```
public static int min(int a, int b) {
    return (a <= b) ? a : b;
}
```

The conditional operator resolves to much the same machine code as the if-statement; assignment to a local variable is virtually free and happens anyway at the machine code level because all intermediate results must be stored *somewhere*.

If your loop is detected as a hot spot while executing your program, the JIT compiler will inline the complete code of `Math.min` into your loop. At that point there will be virtually no difference between the two options you are considering.

However, the ultimate judge is *measurement* of your code running. If – and only if – you see an actual performance issue, you should first use a profiler to see where exactly the time is spent; never trust your guesses. Then, if it does turn out that this particular loop is the bottleneck, you could consider testing with both options to see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do [premature optimizations](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Computer_Programming_as_an_Art_.281974.29). Unless this is an extremely critical path of the program, you should favor readability and maintainability of the code over a supposed performance gain.